# VueJS input with v-model accepts only one character

Tags: javascript, vue.js, watch, vue-reactivity

I have this Vue 1 application with a table that has an input for every cell.

The problematic part in particular has 3 fields on a row:

- dx
- sx
- diff

I want that when `dx` and `sx` are filled, `diff` becomes the difference between the two.

To achieve this I set up a watcher for each `dx` and `sx` fields that calculates the difference when both corresponding inputs are filled.

```
'athlete.inputs[testData.edf.abdother.dx.id].comment': function(){
      this.calcDiff('abdother.dx.id')
},

'athlete.inputs[testData.edf.abdother.sx.id].comment': function(){
      this.calcDiff('abdother.sx.id')
},

...
```

```
 calcDiff: function(input){
      console.log('calculating diff', this.athlete);
      input = input.split('.')
      var dx = this.athlete.inputs[this.testData.edf[input[0]]['dx'][input[2]]].comment
      var sx = this.athlete.inputs[this.testData.edf[input[0]]['sx'][input[2]]].comment
      console.log({dx, sx})
      if (!dx || !sx)
        return;
      
      this.athlete.inputs[this.testData.edf[input[0]]['diff'][input[2]]].comment = dx >= sx ? dx - sx : sx - dx 
    },
```

After setting all up I tried changing some values:

- If I enter one character everything works fine
- If I enter a second (or more) characters, suddenly the value of the property becomes null

[image: Logged values]

As you can see from the picture, if I enter 1 it logs the correct value, but if I enter a second value it becomes null. If I delete all the characters but one then it starts working again.

Setting one character in both inputs works as expected, it calculates the difference and places it in the right place.

More characters immediately unsets the variable and empties the field as soon as you unfocus it.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't get your watcher at all? Why don't you watch your v-model? Why use watch instead of a function that triggers on input?

Comment: @Wimanicesir Do you mean using `@input` to call my function?

Comment: Yes, @input="caclDiff()" should work :)

Comment: @Wimanicesir This is a good idea, the problem is that apparently the value of my property gets unset even before getting to the `@input` event. It kinda looks like that it's vue that's deleting the value, even if it should not be possible

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that `String.split()` uses regular expressions in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). Because `.` is the wildcard in regex, your `input.split('.')` is splitting on every character. Try adding a backslash before the `.`

Comment: Tried, but this doesn't appear to be the problem. I use the split function on a "slug" I use to identify which fields I have to check and which to fill. If that was the problem I would expect a "can't read property 'x' of undefined" error or something similar.